# du and df show discrepant amounts of available disk space on my Linux server

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode, df, du

I know that inodes aren't necessarily deallocated with certain removal/deletion methods that users/programs use.  When inodes are still present and pointing to files that have been deleted, but two or more Linux utilities show a discrepancy with the available space, how do I deallocate the inodes that point to the deleted files?

I have no hidden, forgottent-about backup of a file system.  The files deleted were not log files (so restarting the syslog daemon wouldn't apply to this problem).  The two links posted below as of 10:51 AM Pacific time don't apply to my question.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/57098/du-vs-df-difference

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/379831/disk-space-usage-doesnt-add-up-with-df-du?rq=1

Comment: You first of all need to determine what is holding the files open (see links above), then take the appropriate action e.g. restart a service or even reboot the system ... Also note the related questions on the right and search top right.