# Used truncate to create huge file - df is not showing decrease in available space

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am trying to test a disk space monitor we have setup.
For that purpose, I ran `truncate -s 125G /publish/data/bigFile` which should claim enough space for the alert to be triggered.

However, df -h shows for that partition:
`/dev/vdb1       196G   66G  121G  36% /publish/data`
(which is to say, free space has not changed after running the truncate command.)

`ls -lh` on the file shows:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 username users 126G Aug  7 11:27 /publish/data/bigFile`

mount output for /publish/data:
`/dev/vdb1 on /publish/data type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)`

Edit: I also just realize, the numbers do not make sense:
196-66=130gb, so why df says 121gb free in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/379831/disk-space-usage-doesnt-add-up-with-df-du  ?

Comment: That one is about freeing up space. Mine is about filling it up :) I havent found anything like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't see any documentation that supports it, but `truncate` must be creating a sparse file:

**TEST**
`truncate -s 10G testfile`

`du testfile`             # shows the ***occupied*** size

```
   0  testfile
```

`du -h --apparent-size`   # shows ***apparent*** size

```
   10G   testfile
```

**From the du man page:**

> ```
>    --apparent-size
>           print   apparent  sizes,  rather  than  disk  usage;
>           although the apparent size is  usually  smaller,  it
>           may  be  larger  due  to  holes in ('sparse') files,
>           internal fragmentation,  indirect  blocks,  and  the
>           like
> ```

### **fallocate**

Try using `fallocate`, it's very quick and does not create sparse files.

```
fallocate -l 125G filename
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! how do we open a docs bug for truncate, for the docs to reflect this minor detail, in future builds?

Comment: I emailed an enquiry to `bug-coreutils@gnu.org` and received an auto reply which has generated a bug #36963. If you want you can provide more info to the maintainers by emailing `36963@debbugs.gnu.org`.

Comment: @Carmageddon the author has updated the truncate docs: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/

Comment: That was super fast. thanks!

Comment: If your on Mac OS X which doesn't have `fallocate`, try `mkfile`https://stackoverflow.com/a/33478049/714112

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect you're seeing sparse file allocation at work. You can create a huge file but until you write data to it the actual space on the drive isn't committed.

There are probably ways to allocate and actually commit the space but I've not run across them. If you want to ensure the space is physically allocated you can code a simple program to just append data to a file until it is the proper size.

Comment: I tried to `echo "test >> /publish/data/bigFile`and that didnt do it

Comment: Try something line this: "echo 1234567890>x" and then "cat x x x x x x>xx" and then "cat xx xx xx xx xx>x" repeat the second two commands repeatedly until you get the size of file you want.